# Invoking java webservice from c#.net using client certificate authentication

Tags: java, c#, web-services, soap, client-certificates

We have a SOAP 1.1 based java web service which requires client certificate for authentication. Internally it uses Apache WSS4J library for certificate validation. We also have a working Java client from which requests with client certificate gets successfully posted to the web service. The web service could not be upgraded to SOAP 1.2 as it is a legacy system.

However, the C#.net code for connecting to the same java webservice doesn't work. We have tried basic as well as custom bindings.

Here is the code for the java client that works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //create a web service client
    ImportWsImplService srv = new ImportWsImplService(
                                    new URL("https://example.com/ws/import?wsdl"));

    ImportWs wsClient = srv.getWsImplPort();

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(wsClient);
    Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();

    //change the endpoint url in the wsdl is with http we need to call on https. 
    String endpointURL = "https://example.com/ws/import";
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)wsClient;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointURL);


    Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE);
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_USER, "<<key store alias>>");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, App.class.getName());


    /* client_sign.properties contains
                    org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
                    org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
                    org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=kpassowrd
                    org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=myalias
                    org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=keystorefile.jks
    */
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "client_sign.properties");

    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
    cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

    Response result = wsClient.import();

    System.out.println("result=" + result);
}

public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {

    WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];

    pc.setPassword("<<password for key store>>");
}
```

### Here is my C#.net code and binding from the app.config file:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "<<myclientcertthumbprint>>", true);

var request = new importRequest();
ImportWSClient client = new ImportWSClient();

client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate= certs[0];

var response = client.import(request);
```

### Here is my custom binding in app.config

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="AcknowledgeExportCustomersWSImplServiceSoapBinding">
  <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10"   />
  <security messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature"
            messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
           authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex" >
  </security>
  <httpsTransport  maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" ></httpsTransport>
</binding>
</customBinding>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Update:
We also tried using WSE3 but no luck. Following is the code:
`var filePath = @"c:\\cert.pfx";
            var certX509 = new X509Certificate2(filePath, "pwd", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
            var certToken = new X509SecurityToken(certX509);
            var proxy = new CustomerWsImplService();
            proxy.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(certToken);
            var signature = new MessageSignature(certToken);            
            proxy.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add(signature);
            proxy.importCust(new custRequest());
`

Comment: Resolved– 
1. Use the following custom binding:  
<binding name="customB">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
        <security enableUnsecuredResponse="true" authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" includeTimestamp="false"
          securityHeaderLayout="Lax" allowInsecureTransport="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10" >
        </security>
        <httpsTransport />
</binding>   
2. In Reference.cs file add “ProtectionLevel =System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign” to the method.